# Time and Date checking

Tags: java, date, time

I'm working on a simple online game. It features a chat option, and moderators will have the option to administer a 1 - 24 hour mute.

I was wondering how I could grab the date upon mute, or grab the time upon mute so that I can check.

For example:

Player gets muted for 1 hour at  14:32. They should be unmuted at 15:32.

Or:

Player gets muted for 24 hours at March 21 2015 @ 14:32  - Will be unmuted at March 22 2015 @ 14:32.

How do I test this in Java?

Comment: I can summarize your question as "I want to do time stuff.  Show me teh codez."   That is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  We aren't here to write code for you.  You have to show some effort on your own. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a player is muted just calculate the "unmute" time and store it somewhere:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date()); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
cal.getTime();
```

Other options are some custom libraries:
Apache Commons:

```
DateUtils.addHours(mutedOn, 1);
```

JodaTime:

```
DateTime mutedOn = new DateTime();
DateTime unmuteOn = mutedOn.plusHours(1);
```

Of course you can change the amount and the unit(hours, minutes, days)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using java 8, there is simpler way -

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
dateTime.plusHours(1);
```